# scala 3: value as a class parameter and valueof

Tags: scala, scala-3

I am trying to specify a value as a class parameter:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class MyMap[K,V,D <: V] {
  private val impl = mutable.Map[K, V]()
  def apply(k:K):V = impl.getOrElse(k, valueOf[D])
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ error
  def put(k:K,v:V):Unit = impl += k -> v
}

val m = MyMap[Int, Int, 0]()
m(100) // must return 0
```

For some reason, the above does not work. Instead, what works is the below code with this illogical `unusedName`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class MyMap[K,V,D <: V] {
  private val impl = mutable.Map[K, V]()
  def apply(k:K)(implicit unusedName:ValueOf[D]):V = impl.getOrElse(k, valueOf[D])
  def put(k:K,v:V):Unit = impl += k -> v
}

val m = MyMap[Int, Int, 0]()
m(100) // must return 0
```

I tried to pass the implicit agrument explicitly, which in theory should be possible, but it did not work as I would expect:

```
scala> m(2)(0)
-- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: ----
1 |m(2)(0)
  |     ^
  |     Found:    (0 : Int)
  |     Required: ValueOf[(0 : Int)]

scala> m(2)(ValueOf[0])
-- Error: --------------------------
1 |m(2)(ValueOf[0])
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^
  |     missing arguments for constructor ValueOf in class ValueOf

scala> m(2)(ValueOf[0](0))
val res7: Int = 0
```

**Questions:**

How does all this `ValueOf`/`valueOf` magic work?

Why didn't just `valueOf[D]` work? (It would be only logical)

**UPDATE**

the code referenced in the comments is:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

final class MyMap[K, V] private (default: V) {
  private val impl = mutable.Map.empty[K, V]
  
  def apply(k: K): V =
    impl.getOrElse(k, default)
  
  def put(k: K,v: V): Unit = {
    impl += k -> v
  }
}
object MyMap {
  def empty[K, V, D <: V](using ValueOf[D]): MyMap[K, V] =
    new MyMap(default = valueOf[D])
}

val m = MyMap.empty[Int, Int, 0]
m(100)
```

Code fragment 2:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

final class MyMap[K, V, D <: V](using ValueOf[D]) {
  private val default = valueOf[D]
  private val impl = mutable.Map.empty[K, V]
  
  def apply(k: K): V =
    impl.getOrElse(k, default)
  
  def put(k: K,v: V): Unit = {
    impl += k -> v
  }
}

val m = MyMap[Int, Int, 0]()
m(100)
```

Comment: Just move the implicit parameter to the class constructor: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/pcej8RBGSi64tRswXggBJQ/1

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, your version looks much more meaningful. I tried to get rid of the `default` member, but the compiler created it in the generated .class. `class MyMap<K, V, D extends V>` with `public MyMap(final Object x$1) { this.x$1 = x$1; ...`. The class name `D` appears only once, in `<K, V, D extends V>`. The Java code for `val m = ...` is `MyMap m = new MyMap(BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(0));`.

Comment: That is, **1.** the type parameter `D` becomes a type parameter of the corresponding Java class, even if it's meaningless in Java, and **2.** that Scala-ish "0 as a class" is passed to the constructor as a Java object.

Comment: Well, you may move that to a factory method: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/pcej8RBGSi64tRswXggBJQ/3

Answer (score 0):

> How does all this ValueOf/valueOf magic work?

`ValueOf[T]` is the proposition that there exists one distinguished value of type `T`.

The witness instances for all reasonable types `T` are generated by the compiler automatically.

For each `v: ValueOf[T]`, the member access `v.value` gives the distinguished value of type `T`.

The method `valueOf[T]` is just unpacking the witnesses `ValueOf[T]` into the values of type `T`.

It could be somewhat instructive to quickly re-build this mechanism from scratch:

```
case class MyValueOf[T](value: T)

// For ValueOf, these proofs are generated automatically by the compiler;
// Here, we have to do it ourselves
given MyValueOf[0] = MyValueOf(0)

def myValueOf[A](using mvo: MyValueOf[A]): A = mvo.value

println(summon[MyValueOf[0]]) // MyValueOf(0), the proof
println(myValueOf[0])         // 0, the value
```

> Why didn't just `valueOf[D]` work? (It would be only logical)

Because, as the signature says, the method `valueOf[D]` requires a `ValueOf[D]` as implicit argument. The instances of `ValueOf[D]` can be generated when the `D` is known. It can not be generated for arbitrary generic type `D` (if that were the case, then your code would work for a `Map[Int, Int, Nothing]`, which is clearly absurd).

---

Regarding your REPL experiments:

- `m(2)(0)` clearly shouldn't work, because `0` is of type `Int`, not `ValueOf[Int]`.
- `ValueOf[0]` is interpreted as an incomplete constructor invocation. If you meant the type instead of the value, you would have to use `summon` to materialize the value for the type, i.e. `m(2)(summon[ValueOf[0]])`
- `ValueOf[0](0)` is basically the same as what the compiler would generate anyway when asked to `summon[ValueOf[0]]`.

---

Regarding your `Map`-wrapper:

You probably want to pass the default value once, when you create the map:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class MyMap[K, V, D <: V](using defaultValueOf: ValueOf[D]) {
  private val impl = mutable.Map[K, V]()
  def apply(k: K): V = impl.getOrElse(k, valueOf[D])
  def put(k: K, v: V): Unit = impl += k -> v
}

val m = MyMap[Int, Int, 0]()
println(m(100)) // prints '0'
```

The wrapper itself does not seem to be very helpful, because there is already a method `withDefault` defined on all mutable maps.